# expected an indented block in python with flask

Tags: python, flask, syntax-error

I getting this error when Im trying to get a response from a trainig data and I'm not sure why:

"expected an indented block (, line 55)pylint(syntax-error)"

here is the code

```
app = Flask(__name__);
CORS(app)
@app.route("/bot", methods=["POST"])

#response
def response():
    query = dict(request.form)['query']
   # res = query + " " 
    sentence = tokenize(sentence)
    X = bag_of_words(sentence, all_words)
    X = X.reshape(1, X.shape[0])
    X = torch.from_numpy(X).to(device)

    output = model(X)
    _, predicted = torch.max(output, dim=1)

    tag = tags[predicted.item()]

    probs = torch.softmax(output, dim=1)
    prob = probs[0][predicted.item()]
    if prob.item() > 0.75:
        for intent in intents['intents']:
            if tag == intent["tag"]:
                
    # print(f"{bot_name}: {random.choice(intent['responses'])}")
    return jsonify({"response" :  random.choice(intent['responses'])}) #HERE IS THE ERROR
    
    else:
        return jsonify({"response" : "I do not understand..."})
     
if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0",)
```

The idea of that random choices is to get a a response that cumply some characteristics that I define before....

Comment: You need an instruction indented in your `if tag == intent["tag"]:`. So I guess you need to add 3 indentation level to the line in error.

Comment: Also, there’s no need to write semicolons after each line in python - please remove the semicolon in the first line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you created a if condition and did not write any statements in it. That is why it is causing the error.
Line `return jsonify({"response": random.choice(intent['responses'])})` should be inside the if condition `if tag == intent["tag"]`.

```
if prob.item() > 0.75:
    for intent in intents['intents']:
        if tag == intent["tag"]:

# print(f"{bot_name}: {random.choice(intent['responses'])}")
            return jsonify({"response": random.choice(intent['responses'])})  # HERE IS THE ERROR

else:
    return jsonify({"response": "I do not understand..."})
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be in this line, could you please check if the indentations are appropriate in this block

```
if prob.item() > 0.75:
        for intent in intents['intents']:
            if tag == intent["tag"]:
```